# LaTeX Beamer http request (Media9)

Tags: latex, httprequest, beamer

I am trying to make a survey a part of my beamer presentation. So the idea is that I have made a webpage, where one can input a number:

https://martinbytes.com/numbers/

which then saves it on the server. Then I have another webpage, which by a simple http request calculates the average of the numbers people have put in:

https://martinbytes.com/numbers/result.php

What I now want to do is to implement this into my beamer presentation. So on one slide I give them the first webpage and for instance asks them to evaluate the course on a scale 1-10, then when I change the slide I want the average to be on the slide by loading the second webpage into the presentation at the time the slide opens.

What I have tried so far is to use the media9 package, but I can not make it work. This is what I have so far:

```
\includemedia[                                                                                                                                                                                                      
width=0.46\linewidth,height=0.2\linewidth,                                                                        
activate=pageopen, deactivate=pageclose,                                                                                            
flashvars={                                                                                                       
   src=https://martinbytes.com/numbers/result.php                                                                                                                                              
},                                                                                                                
]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}%
```

But this gives me TypeError - Error#1009. How can I fix this?